# WPF Executing two alternating UI tasks

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading

I have a WPF UI with Helix3DToolkit Graphics in it.

I had two buttons there,

1st button - Adds some Visual3D objects into it.

2nd button - Saves a screenshot of the current UI into a jpeg image by using
Code for screenshot:

```
Viewport3DHelper.Export(vp.Viewport, filename);
```

All this works fine manually. But now I want to make this automatic. (Several alternating rounds of actions of buttons 1 & 2. i.e. I want to just press one button, which will add some boxes, save a screenshot, add some more, save a screenshot, etc.)

I can control the buttons programmatically by using the following:

```
ButtonAutomationPeer peer = new ButtonAutomationPeer(MyButton);
IInvokeProvider invokeProv = peer.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Invoke) as IInvokeProvider;
invokeProv.Invoke();
```

But when I do this, all I get is several copies of the same UI. (This is due to the nature of the UI thread, I believe)

I found a partial solution, which is to use,

```
TaskScheduler scheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken();

Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetScreenShotAction()).ContinueWith(w =>
{
            AddBoxes();
}, cancellationToken, TaskContinuationOptions.None, scheduler);
```

But, this is also not working properly (it's working randomly, when I take only 2 screenshots, but never when it's more than 2). This is probably because both the before and after actions are on the UI thread.

Any ideas on how to get this done will be hugely appreciated.

Also I'm using VC# 2010 with .NET 4 framework. So cannot use `async` and `await`.

Thanks!

### Update

I'm already using, `this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => { ... }));` in the `GetScreenShotAction` method. And, the other action `AddBoxes` is on the same thread.

Also, it works randomly, so I'm guessing that because I'm invoking the Dispatcher, both are still happening technically on the same thread.

Comment: I suspect that the screenshot action is happening before the ui has had chance to render it's changes from adding the controls to the visual tree. I don't know off the top of my head how to say 'wait for everything to be rendered', but perhaps you could test the theory by introducing a delay before taking the screenshot...? Obviously this delay would be only for testing and shouldn't be used as the solution if that is the problem... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you need to wait for the UI to render (after modifying the visual tree by adding your buttons and what not) before you take your screenshot.

[This article](http://geekswithblogs.net/NewThingsILearned/archive/2008/08/25/refresh--update-wpf-controls.aspx) shows how to use the dispatcher with `DispatcherPriority.Render` to get the code to wait for all the rendering to be done before continuing.

To quote the article:

> When the DispatcherPriority is set to Render (or lower), the code will
>   then execute all operations that are of that priority or higher.  In
>   the example, the code already sets label1.Content to something else,
>   which will result in a render operation.  So by calling
>   Dispatcher.Invoke, the code essentially asks the system to execute all
>   operations that are Render or higher priority, thus the control will
>   then render itself (drawing the new content).  Afterwards, it will
>   then execute the provided delegate (which is our empty method).

The code for the Refresh extension method:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
   private static Action EmptyDelegate = delegate() { };

   public static void Refresh(this UIElement uiElement)
   {
      uiElement.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, EmptyDelegate);
   }
}
```

Use it something like:

```
AddBoxes();
MyControlContainer.Refresh();
TakeScreenShot();
```

Where `MyControlContainer` is a `UIElement`, maybe the container that you added the boxes to?

Comment: I'll just add a comment that I have no experience of the 3DHelixToolkit and how that might affect rendering...

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this and let you know whether it works!

Comment: It worked. Thanks! but I had to use `DispatcherPriority.Background` instead of `DispatcherPriority.Render`

Probably `Render` was not enough lower priority to let the UI refresh.

It's true this is sort of a gimmick.. but as long as it works I'm thankful :D

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track using a `Task` to multi-thread the operation. The issue is that you need to `Invoke` your code on the correct `Thread`. Use the `Dispatcher` (aka WPF UI Thread) to do this via `Application.Current.Dispatcher` by calling `Invoke()` or `BeginInvoke()` as desired.

Comment: I'm already using, `this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => { ... }));` in the `GetScreenShotAction` method. And, the other action `AddBoxes` is on the same thread.

Also, it works randomly, so I'm guessing that because I'm invoking the Dispatcher, both are still happening technically on the same thread.

What do you think of this?